# Disable a function for a specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a function that scans a barcode or QR code and returns the result:

```
    function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
        console.log(`Code scanned = ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);
    }
    var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
        "qr-reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
    html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
```

It works great but the problem i have is that it scans the code very fast and multiple times.

[image]

Is there a way to timeout the function so it only return the scans every second?

Comment: This sounds like what you're looking for- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: It's like, definitely not a built-in function, have you tried tweaking fps? I can see a full instruction here: https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode. Either way, it looks like it works as intended, I would just drop a `while` loop to stop scanning once QR code is obtained (also you could use promise provided by this library, see the link).

Comment: Thank you very much @nicael the tweaking with the fps worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks for all the answers and comments.

In the end it worked with the tweaking of the fps. I changed the fps: 10 to fps: 1. Thanks @nicael for that answer.

```
var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "qr-reader", { fps: 1, qrbox: 250 });
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
```

If you searched for an answer to disable a function for a specific time, look at @Alireza Jahandoost answer that one's perfect for that case.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do that is to set a flag variable and console.log the result if the flag is true. something like that:

```
    var flag = true;
    function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
        if(flag){
            console.log(`Code scanned = ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    setInterval(()=>flag=true, 1000);

    var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
        "qr-reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
    html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
```

There's another way too. we can change the flag with setTimeout in the onScanSuccess function.

```
    var flag = true;
    function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
        if(flag){
            console.log(`Code scanned = ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);
            flag = false;
            setTimeout(()=>flag=true, 1000);
        }
    }

    var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
        "qr-reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
    html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
```

Comment: Alternative:  `if (!flag) return; flag=false; ...continue with event...`